# Neo4j APOC oracle url connection string from cypher

Tags: oracle, neo4j

Need url string for Neo4j APOC with remote Oracle database (the below example is for mysql):

```
with "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/northwind?user=root" as url             
cypher CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"products") YIELD row     
RETURN count(*);
```

Similar to above for oracle we have to consider the following SID, user, password,

Answer (score 1):

Download the Oracle JDBC driver from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html

put it into `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins`

Use this kind of JDBC URL:

- `jdbc:oracle:thin:<username/password>@hostname:port/service_name` or
- `jdbc:oracle:thin:<username/password>@hostname:port:SID`

You can also put it into your `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`

`apoc.jdbc.oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:...`

Comment: How do we read the properties of neo4j.conf ? like apoc.jdbc.oracle.url you mentioned

Comment: apoc does it internally

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael,
I got it myself, and followed the sample way.

URL string : jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@hostname:port:SID
jdbc driver: ojdbcr6.jar  in the $neo_home/plugins

Adding it to the neo4j.conf is right thing to do.

Comment: did it work? we could add it as example to the apoc docs, for the different databases